# Android camera input similar to xbox kinect

Tags: android

This is probably not possible but are there any API's that allow camera input on Android similar to what is possible with the Xbox kinect. Simpler capabilities I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

The kinect camera isn't anything special. It's just a regular webcam-type sensor. But the kinect DOES have a projector in that fires out a grid of infrared dots which the camera sensor picks up. It's those dots that let the Kinect software/hardware do its magic.

Here's a youtube vid that shows the dots: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvvQJxgykcU

You could probably run the basic image analysis software on Android, but without the projected dots, most of what the Kinect does isn't possible with JUST the camera.

Comment: I've seen some videos on how it works. I was just wondering if there are any remotely similar API's already being developed